# UIImagePickerControllerでExceptioエラーがでますが、原因が分かりません。

Tags: swift, firebase, uiimagepickercontroller

画像をタップしてアルバムから画像を選択した時にエラーで止まります。
現状のコードは他のプロジェクトファイルにコピペして実行した所、問題なく動作しているので何が原因なのかが分からないです。

以下、現状のソースです。

```
@IBAction func tapProfileImage(_ sender: Any) {
    showAlert()
}



func souceTypeImagePicker(souceType:UIImagePickerController.SourceType){

    let cameraPicker = UIImagePickerController()
        cameraPicker.sourceType = souceType
        cameraPicker.delegate = self
        cameraPicker.allowsEditing = true
        present(cameraPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    if let pickerImage = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage{
        self.profileImage.image = pickerImage
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}


func showAlert(){

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "選択", message: "どちらを使用しますか?", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "カメラ", style: .default) { (alert) in

            let souceType:UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .camera
                self.souceTypeImagePicker(souceType: souceType)

        }
    let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "アルバム", style: .default) { (alert) in

        let souceType:UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.souceTypeImagePicker(souceType: souceType)

    }

    let action3 = UIAlertAction(title: "キャンセル", style: .cancel)


        alertController.addAction(action1)
        alertController.addAction(action2)
        alertController.addAction(action3)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

セキュアについてはモデル化してインスタンス化し、Viewdidload内で実行しています。

以下モデルです。

```
class checkPermission{

    init() {

    }

    func checkCamera(){
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
            switch(status){


            case .notDetermined:
                print("notDetermined")
            case .restricted:
                print("restricted")
            case .denied:
                print("denied")
            case .authorized:
                print("authorized")
            case .limited:
                print("limited")
            @unknown default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

今回の問題になっているこれらのコードを別のプロジェクトファイルにてコピペで実行した際は正常に動作し、アルバムから画像を選択できている状態でした。
問題が発生しているプロジェクトとの違いはFirebaseがインストールされているかいないかの違いです。しかし、問題が発生しているプロジェクトで画像を選択してもまだFirebaseに対して何もデータを送信していないのであまり関係ないと思うのですが、Firebaseがインストールされていないプロジェクトでは正常に動作するのでよく分からないです。

動作環境はM1のMacBook Proです。
画像を含めないFirebase通信ではarm64を使用しないに設定して正常に動作していました。

アドバイスよろしくお願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 可能な限りエラーメッセージは画像ではなく、テキストとして本文中に記載して下さい。回答を考える人が検索したり、同じエラーで苦しんでいる人がこのスレッドを見つけやすくなります。なお、単に「これらのコードを別のプロジェクトファイルにてコピペで実行した際は正常に動作」と言われてもどんなプロジェクトのどのような場所にコピペしたのかがわからないと、それが何か意味があるかどうかはなんとも言えません。

Comment: コピーしたのは画像を選択する部分だけを新規プロジェクトを作成して貼り付けました。つまり、単にUIImageだけを設置してタップした時に画像をライブラリーから選択するだけのプロジェクトファイルです。この事から画像選択するPickerには問題がないと推測できました。

Comment: 「この事から画像選択するPickerには問題がないと推測できました。」すいませんが、貼り付け先のプロジェクトがどんなものかわからないのにそんなことを書かれても、同じ結論は出せません。

Comment: すみません。貼り付け先のプロジェクトは画面１枚にUIImageが１つあるだけのファイルです。そのファイルを選択してアルバムから選択できました。
色々ご指摘頂いて申し訳ございませんが、とりあえずIntelMacではこのまま動作するのでM1Macを使わないと言うとこで解決で解決します。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: ご報告ありがとうございます。何か私でも解決に役立てる情報が得られるかと思ってのことなのでしつこくあれこれお願いしたことについてはご容赦ください。今回は「M1Macを使わない」と言う解決策を取られるようですが、M1Macでの解決方法などはっきりしましたら、自己回答の形でご経験をシェアしていただけると助かります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。M1はFirebase系で色々問題があるので分かり次第ご報告致します！

Answer (score 1):

`URLByAppendingPathExtension`という場所（すなわち、`appendingPathExtension(_:)`関数
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1780122-appendingpathextension ）で例外エラーが発生していますね。

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/670640
にのっているエラー文が質問にのせてある画像に入っているエラー文に非常に似ていて、同じような場所で問題が発生しているのだと思います。

---

**どこでエラーが出ているかを書いて、画像ではなくエラー文をコピペしたほうが、回答する側としてもわかりやすく、回答されやすい**と思うので、今度から心がけましょう。

Exceptio → Exception